# Docker container not starting locally

Tags: mysql, docker

I am running into issues trying to start my database locally with Docker. I keep receiving the error:

```
2022-03-05 15:43:51+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.31-1debian10 started.
2022-03-05 15:43:51+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-03-05 15:43:51+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.31-1debian10 started.
2022-03-05 15:43:51+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
2022-03-05T15:43:51.943066Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2022-03-05T15:43:51.974145Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Retry attempts for writing partial data failed.
2022-03-05T15:43:51.974211Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Write to file ./ibdata1failed at offset 0, 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 0 were written. Operating system error number 28. Check that your OS and file system support files of this size. Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
2022-03-05T15:43:51.974224Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'
2022-03-05T15:43:51.974231Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not set the file size of './ibdata1'. Probably out of disk space
2022-03-05T15:43:51.974239Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: InnoDB Database creation was aborted with error Generic error. You may need to delete the ibdata1 file before trying to start up again.
2022-03-05T15:43:52.592357Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-03-05T15:43:52.592450Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-03-05T15:43:52.592464Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2022-03-05T15:43:52.592467Z 0 [ERROR] Abortin
```

I've removed at least 5GB of data off of my machine, but the problem still persists. What is the cause of it?

Comment: `InnoDB: Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'` is the error. Check in which partition you are, and also run `df -iH` to see if you have available inodes

Comment: ```
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5    1.0T    11G   8.3G    58%  488389 9767489771    0%   /
devfs           198k   198k     0B   100%     675          0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s1    1.0T   979G   8.3G   100% 3903099 9764075061    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
/dev/disk1s4    1.0T   1.1G   8.3G    12%       1 9767978159    0%   /private/var/vm
map auto_home     0B     0B     0B   100%       0          0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/home
```